# Connect Four C++ drop function is not working correctly

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with my code for connect 4. It works until the bottom second line and instead of going to the third line it just replaces the second line. Is it my drop function that is wrong or my main function?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void drop(int b[][7], int column, int disc)//drops the game pieces  {
    for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--)//starts at 5(the bottom) {
        if (b[i][column - 1] == 0)//if row 5 is not filled it will be 1
        {
            b[i][column - 1] = disc;
            break;
        }
        if (b[i][column - 1] != 0)//if row 5 is filled go to next row
        {
            b[i - 1][column - 1] = disc;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void display(int c[][7])//displays the gameboard
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            cout << c[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void initial(int arr[][7])//sets the initial gameboard with all 0's
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
         {
             arr[i][j] = 0;
         }
     }
}
void main()
{
    int a[6][7];//declare the 2d array 
    int column;//declares the variable for column
    initial(a);
    display(a);//prints the initial 
    cout << "Enter 0 if you win or want to quit"<<endl;//user exit
    for (;;)//infinite for loop so the game will continue until user exits
    {
        cout << "Enter column 1-7 ";
        cin >> column;//reading in what the user has inputted
        if (column == 0)//if it is 0 the program will end
            break;
        drop(a, column, 1);//player 1
        display(a);//displays board after player 1 put piece in
        cout << "Enter column 1-7 ";
        cin >> column;
        if (column == 0)
            break;
        drop(a, column, 2);//player 2
        display(a);//displays board after player 2 put piece in
    }
}
```

Comment: `void main`, C++? Really. Also why not use `std::array` or `std::vector`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You shouldn't have two if statements inside your drop function, that's why you already have a loop, simplify that bit.

Answer (score 0):

It's your drop function:

```
void drop(int b[][7], int column, int disc)//drops the game pieces  
{
for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--)//starts at 5(the bottom) {
    if (b[i][column - 1] == 0)//if row 5 is not filled it will be 1
    {
        b[i][column - 1] = disc;
        break;
    }
    if (b[i][column - 1] != 0)//if row 5 is filled go to next row
    {
        b[i - 1][column - 1] = disc;
        break;
    }
}
```

the if statement "if row 5 is filled go to next row" places the disc in row 4 if row 5 is filled, but it's not actually bothering to check whether row 4 is empty. Get rid of this if statement, you only need the first if statement. "going to the next row" is already handled by the for loop.

Get that working first, then you should also return a bool: false if there's no room, true if the counter was placed. Then you can ask the player to try different columns if they pick a full one.